# Get object in session without managed bean

Tags: jsf, managed-bean

Hello placed a managedbean in session scope named loginBean and Im trying to get that object from a xhtml without managed bean, I tried this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{loginBean.user.userName}" />
```

but it doesnt work, so put this line to see if the object is already in session:

```
<h:outputText value="#{sessionScope}" />
```

and yes, the bean is there:

```
loginBean=com.bean.LoginBean@1dfae73, javax.faces.request.charset=UTF-8}
```

how I can access it without Managed Bean, directly from xhtml?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello BalusC, thanks for answer, well i put <h:outputText value="#{sessionScope}" />  to see the objects in session and i see {com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.LogicalViewMap={839306770636811414={4245116754698124366=[Ljava.lang.Object;@1642ee5}}, loginBean=com.bean.LoginBean@1dfae73, javax.faces.request.charset=UTF-8}, i supossed that this mean that the object is in session.. if loginBean was null i think that i see loginBean=null, instead com.bean.LoginBean@1dfae73... im wrong?

Comment: additionally i can say that i access to loginBean object from another ManagedBean @ManagedProperty(value="#{loginBean}"), and i is not null... Thanks

Comment: no, i want print some attribute, but i dont know how access it...

Comment: 're right, the user was null, excuse the trouble I'm new at this .. Thankx!

Comment: BalusC can u help me with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389506/primefaces-change-center-layout-with-menubar thanks in advance!