# How To Load a jsf page to another center layout unit

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am new To JSf Technology and am creating a system where by am using primefaces. I am using Layoutunit in primefaces and I have left,north and south layoutunit. I want my menus to be on the west layout unit and the content to be in the center unit. I want when a menu is clicked to load corresponding jsf page to the center layout. How can I achieve this? here is my sample code.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north">
            <p>Header Here</p>
        </p:layoutUnit>
         <p:layoutUnit position="west">
              <p:menu >
                    <p:submenu label="Application" icon="ui-icon-refresh">
                        <p:menuitem value="Page One" 
                                    ajax="false" 
                                    actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" />
                        <p:menuitem value="Page Two" 
                                    ajax="false" 
                                    actionListener="#{bean.setPage('page1')}"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menu>
        </p:layoutUnit>
         <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <p>Content Here</p>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use JSF Templating. An example has been shown is this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26389506/primefaces-change-center-layout-with-menubar/26395906#26395906)